# Attempt to retrieve data for object failed for Server (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

Tags: sql-server

I have two databases, one hosted in Azure SQL Server and another one which is local on my own SQL Server instance. Both of these I manage using SSMS.

I wanted to see how I can backup the Azure DB and restore it on the local instance (where I currently have other databases as well, generated and managed by Entity Framework) of my SQL Server. For that purpose, I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OCWsw8D2SnA) video.

What I basically did was to export a `.bacpac` file and restore it on my local instance by making a reference to "Import Data-Tier application".

Everything went well. The content was successfully restored and I was able to browse through it. When I finished with my testing I manually deleted this new database.

From that moment on, I can not access my other databases at all. When I try to do whatever SQL query on those I get the following error:

> Attempt to retrieve data for object failed for Server '**********'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> Failed to retrieve data for this request. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc)
>
> An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>
> The connection is broken and recovery is not possible.  The client driver attempted to recover the connection one or more times and all attempts failed.  Increase the value of ConnectRetryCount to increase the number of recovery attempts. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 0)
>
> Cannot open database "{THE NAME OF THE DB THAT I MANUALLY DELETED}" requested by the login. The login failed.
> Login failed for user ******************'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 4060)

Comment: Your connection string specifies a certain database, which has now been deleted. Maybe connect to `master` instead?

Comment: @Charlieface If I go to SSMS, click on the 'New Query' toolbox menu option and I manually type SELECT * FROM [MyDb].[dbo].[MyTable] it returns content. But if I right-click on the table MyTable and pick the option 'Select top 1000 rows' I get this error that I posted.

Comment: Try refreshing the Databases node in Object Explorer. It does not dynamically update with changes on the server and so could be caching information with old/deceased dbid and objectid values.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Have already tried it. Not working.

Comment: @user2128702 did you ever find a solution for this issue?